# AngularJS $http.post(..) - Error: $http is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying out AngularJS for the first time. When using the `$http.post("url", data)` function, I'm getting a `Error: $http is not defined` console message.

At the top of my HTML page I am including AngularJS after all other JS imports.

I have also included other JavaScript libraries due to widget dependencies etc. My script imports section looks like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I have a controller which I'm using to send some data to the server:

```
function FormCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.sendData = function(){
        var data = "firstName=" + $scope.firstName + "&" +
            "lastName=" + $scope.lastName + "&" +
            "address=" + $scope.address + "&" +
            "postcode=" + $scope.postcode;

        $http.post("/data/person/put", data);
     };
}
```

The `sendData` function is attached to a button. All works fine until the call to `$http.post(...)` at which point the console outputs the error.

The full error listing is:

```
Error: $http is not defined
$scope.sendData@http://localhost:8080/angularjs/:96
Mc/x/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js:71
ec[c]</</</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js:142
e.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js:87
e.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js:87
ec[c]</</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js:142
c.event.handle@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js:63
c.event.add/o@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js:57

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js
Line 61
```

Do I have to do something else to configure AngularJS to use the `$http.post` function?

I lifted the usage straight from the AngularJS **Shortcut Methods** section of the documentation here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Can anyone help?

Thanks 
Adam

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`function FormCtrl($scope) {` should be `function FormCtrl($scope, $http) {`.

You need to inject all the services required to the controller, in this case you are using `$scope` and `$http` service, but you have injected only `$scope` that is the cause of the error.

Ex:

```
function FormCtrl($scope, $http) {
    ....
}
FormCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

You can read a note about complications in injection with minification [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05), read `A Note on Minification`

Comment: Tried it out and fully working now. Thank you for quick response. So quick that I can't even accept your answer yet. But I will. Thanks again!

Comment: You can read a note about complications in injection with minification at http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05